# How to open Google Maps mobile App from a Web application

Tags: javascript, facebook-messenger-bot, chatfuel

So i need to redirect users to google maps mobile app when they click on the button ! (PS : i m using Chatfuel messsenger chatbot JSON API response [chatfuel JSON API](https://docs.chatfuel.com/api/json-api/json-api) )

I've tried these links but it didn't work for me :

```
comgooglemaps://?center=40.765819,-73.975866&zoom=14&views=traffic"
```

When i use this link

```
 https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin="+latitude+","+longitude+"&destination="+loc.latitude+","+loc.longitude+"&travelmode=transport?v=%20",
```

I get this result

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I think the universal protocol for map is "geo://" (with coordinate and it will prompt for asking which app the user want to use) but the "maps://" protocol works on most devices too (certainly with gmaps options).
"comgooglemaps://" is for ios only.

Comment: can you give an example please